# Calling two functions in C++ and passing them the same delegate in C#

Tags: .net, delegates, marshalling

I have C++ project with functions:

```
_API void __stdcall  InstallMailHandler(MailHdlPtrType Hdl)
{ ... }
_API void __stdcall  UninstallMailHandler(MailHdlPtrType Hdl)
{ ... }

typedef void (STDCALL  *MailHdlPtrType)(unsigned char instNo, bla bla bla);
```

And I have in C#:

```
public static extern void InstallMailHandler(MailHdlPtrType Hdl);
public static extern void UninstallMailHandler(MailHdlPtrType Hdl);

public delegate void MailHdlPtrType(byte instno, bla bla bla);
```

But when I call InstallMailHandler and UninstallMailHandler from C# with the same function in arguments, it results in different addresses in C++ so it cannot uninstall previously installed mail handler.

Is it possible to somehow ensure that both invokes will result in the same function address, or maybe set an address explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the new delegate object is created in each call.

You probably call them like that:

```
InstallMailHandler(new MailHdlPtrType(YourCoolFunction));
// ...
UninstallMailHandler(new MailHdlPtrType(YourCoolFunction));
```

or in equivalent short form:

```
InstallMailHandler(YourCoolFunction);
// ...
UnnstallMailHandler(YourCoolFunction);
```

I think you just need to keep the same delegate:

```
MailHdlPtrType my_deleg = new MailHdlPtrType(YourCoolFunction); // this may be field in your class or something
//...
InstallMailHandler(my_deleg);
// ...
UnnstallMailHandler(my_deleg);
```

Comment: Yes, I believe this is the problem. the .NET GC will JIT a new function with the `this` pointer in both cases, most likely.